# IOS: add some sub-scrollview in a scrollview, image don't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *image = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], nil];

for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollV.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollV.frame.size;

    UIScrollView *subScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [subview setImage:[image objectAtIndex:i]];
    [subScrollView addSubview:subview];
    [scrollV addSubview:subScrollView];
    [subview release];
    [subScrollView release];
}

scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollV.frame.size.width * image.count, scrollV.frame.size.height);

}
```

scrollV is the main scrollview and it have "paging enabled"
if I use this code I have my scrollV with paging enabled but I see inside it only "1.png" at first page, I don't see others png, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're settings the frame of `subview` to the incorrect value. That is making it the same frame as its `subScrollView` so it's pushing it off to the right. Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *image = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], nil];

for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollV.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollV.frame.size;

    UIScrollView *subScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

    UIImage *image = [image objectAtIndex:i];
    subScrollView.contentSize = image.size;

    [subview setImage:image];
    [subScrollView addSubview:subview];
    [scrollV addSubview:subScrollView];
    [subview release];
    [subScrollView release];
}

scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollV.frame.size.width * image.count, scrollV.frame.size.height);

}
```

Edit: Also probably best to set the content size of the inner scrollview. I added code to that effect above.